# How do you make clang link directly to a DLL in Windows without a .lib

Tags: c, windows, dll, clang, lib

TinyCC and GCC both have supported lib-less linking, in favor of directly linking to a DLL file for some time (since lib's haven't had real purpose since Win3.1). But for some reason in Windows, Clang insists on interpreting the .dll file as a .lib file.  According to LLVM's page, here, https://lld.llvm.org/windows_support.html, `lld-link` does support direct dll linkage, but in practice, I'm not seeing any way to specify. (This is true with LLVM 10.0 and 11.0)

To be clear, I'm not referring to manual loading with `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.  I'm referring to invoking the compiler like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\gcc" -o rdtest.exe rdtest.c -lgdi32 -luser32 openvr_api.dll C:\windows\system32\opengl32.dll C:\windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
```

^^ Works

```
"C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe" -fuse-ld=lld-link -v -o rdtest.exe rdtest.c -lgdi32 -luser32 openvr_api.dll C:\windows\system32\opengl32.dll C:\windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
[...]
1 warning generated.
 "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\lld-link" -out:rdtest.exe -defaultlib:libcmt "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\lib\\x64" "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\atlmfc\\lib\\x64" "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.18362.0\\ucrt\\x64" "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.18362.0\\um\\x64" -nologo "C:\\Users\\cnlohr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rdtest-a9472b.o" gdi32.lib user32.lib openvr_api.dll "C:\\windows\\system32\\opengl32.dll" "C:\\windows\\system32\\msvcrt.dll"
lld-link: error: openvr_api.dll: bad file type. Did you specify a DLL instead of an import library?
lld-link: error: C:\windows\system32\opengl32.dll: bad file type. Did you specify a DLL instead of an import library?
lld-link: error: C:\windows\system32\msvcrt.dll: bad file type. Did you specify a DLL instead of an import library?
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

^^ Fails

Comment: *since lib's haven't had real purpose since Win3.1* Could you elaborate on that? Maybe some citations?

Comment: _"interpreting the .dll file as a .lib file"_,  A lib file in CLANG or any other build environment is simply a map of what is in the .dll file.

Comment: DLL's have contained a map of their contents since the Windows 95 era, and thus, over time compilers have just linked directly to DLLs.  There is no longer an explicit need for LIB files.  They're a nice-to-have because it lets you link without the DLL present, but still optional, not required.

Comment: @CharlesLohr - what you written is absolute mistake. dll containing only names of exported function. lib can and usually containing more info. it special design for build process. in what problem use lib files ?

Comment: Note that ClangCL / LLD-link try to be binary and command-line compatible with MSVC, which is not one of MinGW's goals. It would not surprise me if MinGW and TinyCC added extra information to the DLLs that `link.exe` would reject.

Comment: The bounty note says using MinGW but the question asks about clang ... please clarify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was implemented recently upstream https://reviews.llvm.org/rGa9ff1ce1b9a52add7557cf0579d424c9d0678860 and was backported to the MSYS2 llvm package.

Comment: You need the flag "/lldmingw" to make it work with "lld-link.exe".
Tested with:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin\lld-link.exe" --version
LLD 15.0.1

Answer (score 2):

You are misreading LLVM's documentation. I believe the part you are referring to is:

> Linking against DLL
>
> **Done.** LLD can read import libraries needed to link against DLL. Both export-by-name and export-by-ordinal are supported.

They do not mean the same thing as MinGW / TinyCC's "direct" (no `.lib`) linking. They mean literally "*LLD can link to shared libraries on Windows and is able to read the `.lib` files to do so*". Which is true, but you still need the `.lib`, just like MSVC does.

So the answer is, unfortunately, **you cannot make Clang/LLD do this at time of writing**.